# Ecto.Repo.insert! with "on_conflict: :nothing" raising a Postgresql "syntax error at or near "ON""

Tags: postgresql, elixir, phoenix-framework, ecto

I'm totally new to Elixir and Phoenix, and am currently working through the book "Programming Phoenix."

I've reached chapter 7 and I have a database table called `categories` with a column `name` and a DB-level uniqueness constraint on `name`.

If I run the following line when a category called "Hello" already exists, I get an `Ecto.ConstraintError` as expected:

```
> Rumbl.Repo.insert!(%Rumbl.Multimedia.Category{name: "Hello"})
[debug] QUERY ERROR db=3.2ms queue=4.9ms idle=9982.9ms
INSERT INTO "categories" ("name","inserted_at","updated_at") VALUES ($1,$2,$3) RETURNING "id" ["Hello", ~N[2020-04-18 07:05:04], ~N[2020-04-18 07:05:04]]
** (Ecto.ConstraintError) constraint error when attempting to insert struct:

    * categories_name_index (unique_constraint)
```

Now, the book tells me that I can add the option `on_conflict: :nothing` to my call to `insert!` and it will prevent an error from being raised. But what actually happens is I get a postgres syntax error:

```
> Rumbl.Repo.insert!(%Rumbl.Multimedia.Category{name: "Hello"}, on_conflict: :nothing)
** (Postgrex.Error) ERROR 42601 (syntax_error) syntax error at or near "ON"

    query: INSERT INTO "categories" ("name","inserted_at","updated_at") VALUES ($1,$2,$3) ON CONFLICT DO NOTHING RETURNING "id"
    (ecto_sql) lib/ecto/adapters/sql.ex:612: Ecto.Adapters.SQL.raise_sql_call_error/1
    (ecto) lib/ecto/repo/schema.ex:657: Ecto.Repo.Schema.apply/4
    (ecto) lib/ecto/repo/schema.ex:263: anonymous fn/15 in Ecto.Repo.Schema.do_insert/4
    (ecto) lib/ecto/repo/schema.ex:164: Ecto.Repo.Schema.insert!/4
[debug] QUERY ERROR db=0.0ms queue=0.8ms idle=9038.9ms
INSERT INTO "categories" ("name","inserted_at","updated_at") VALUES ($1,$2,$3) ON CONFLICT DO NOTHING RETURNING "id" ["Hello", ~N[2020-04-18 07:05:13], ~N[2020-04-18 07:05:13]]
```

Version numbers:

- Elixir 1.9.4
- Phoenix 1.4.10
- Ecto 3.4.2
- Postgres 12.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I was mistaken that my postgres version is `12.1`, this is actually the installed version of my `psql` client and not my postgres *server*, which was running 9.4. `ON CONFLICT` was added in 9.5, so the solution is to upgrade my postgres server.